# Why there are 2 files setting same variables on /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/?

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

`10periodic` and `20auto-upgrades` set at least partially same variables. Why not just use one file? Does the latter one override the settings on the former one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `20auto-upgrades` replaces configuration of `10periodic`. So there are no doubles: Apt will read each file in sequence. The same setting twice then the last one found will be active.
- Not everybody has `20auto-upgrades`. That one is installed when you in stall package `unattended-upgrades`.
- `10periodic` is from package `update-notifier-common` and that one is installed by default.

Comment: Oddly `dpkg-query -S  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` does not report `unattended-upgrades` or any other package.

Comment: @jarno `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades` creates it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates